# SQL injection and prepared statements

Tags: java, security, sql-injection

My teacher and I are having a debate about whether it is possible to SQL inject into a prepared statement.  I understand that normally you couldn't, but the professor insists on using sql concatenation instead of using (?).

Now I am trying to break my code, but I am having no luck.

```
public Users getUserByUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

    sql.append("select * from users as  u, user_type_lookup as l, user_types as t ");
    sql.append("where u.users_id=l.user_id and l.type_id=t.user_types_id and u.username='");
    sql.append(username);
    sql.append("';");

    System.out.println(sql.toString());

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql.toString());

    if (!rs.next()) {
        return null;
    }

    String password = rs.getString("password");
    String type = rs.getString("description");
    int id = rs.getInt("users_id");
    int incorrect_logins = rs.getInt("incorrect_logins");
    Time wait_time = rs.getTime("wait_time");

    Users u = new Users(id, username, password, type, incorrect_logins,
            wait_time);
    return u;
}
```

Inserts I have tried:

```
string: '; DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or users_id = '
string: ';delete from users where username<>'
//The only one that worked    
string: stan' or 'a'<>'b
```

SQL output(Results in a java error):

```
select * from users as  u, user_type_lookup as l, user_types as t where u.users_id=l.user_id and l.type_id=t.user_types_id and u.username=''; DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or users_id = '';
```

SQL output (works as intended):

```
select * from users as  u, user_type_lookup as l, user_types as t where u.users_id=l.user_id and l.type_id=t.user_types_id and u.username='stan';
```

Error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your    
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the   
right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or users_id = ''' at line 1
```

Server: Tomcat 7

Database: MySQL

IDE: Eclipse

Language: Java

So please help me break my code!

Comment: Prepared statements among others ususally escapes values. If values are already escaped, concatenation should be used.

Comment: Although I think this is a good question in terms of "Can Prepared Statements be attacked with SQL Injection"... it isn't really phrased as such... you may want to make it more like a question such that an answer can be provided.

Comment: Even if you were able to inject SQL into that statement, you did it thanks to the way you wrote your code. That is *not* a prepared statement.

Comment: @NullUserException: Isn't that the OP's point?

Comment: @ruakh That would be kind of like handing a thief your car keys and saying "well, normally people wouldn't be able to bypass the alarm, but ...". Safety measures are only useful if you actually use them correctly. In this case, the OP is not using prepared statements at all.

Comment: @NullUserException: Could you elaborate on how what you're saying differs from what the OP is saying? Because I really think you're saying the same thing.

Comment: @ruakh According to the OP, the debate is "whether it is possible to SQL inject into a prepared statement." What the OP is using is not a prepared statement, so injecting code into that statement has nothing to do with the debate in question.

Comment: @NullUserException: According to the OP, the debate is whether it's possible to inject SQL into a *misused* prepared statement, with values being concatenated rather than parameterized. And what the OP is using is exactly that: a misused prepared statement, with values being concatenated rather than parameterized. No?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a separate statement inside the SQL of the prepared-statement, but you *can* break it by, for example:

- using `' OR 'x' = 'x` as the username (so that the query will do a Cartesian join across all users and types mappings between them); this will greatly harm performance if `users` and `user_type_lookup` are large tables, and would be an excellent start on a denial-of-service attack.
- using `' OR (SELECT stored_procedure_that_deletes_things()) = 1` (so that the query will invoke a stored-procedure that has deleterious effects).